# Unable to draw in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, catboost

I am using the catboost model for training, using

```
model. fit (train_pool, eval_set=val_pool, early_stopping_rounds=150, plot=True)'
```

, but in jupyternotebook

```
Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message' Model class' CatboostWidgetModel 'from module' catboost widget 'is loaded but can not be instantiated TypeError: o_ Deserialize_ State is not a function at u_ Make_ Model（ http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/jupyter -Js widgets/extensions. js v=20230721130414:2:752635)
```

is displayed

The solution found was to install the catboost widget library, but encountered an ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost widget error, possibly because you attempted to install the library using pip.
At present, catboost widgets are no longer pip installable, so how can we solve the problem of displaying training loss images in jupiter notebooks?